# How to access jQuery .each's "this" in TypeScript?

Tags: javascript, jquery, typescript

Given the following TypeScript code snippet:

```
export class MyClass {
    myMethod() {
       // ...
       $myQuery.each(function(idx, elm) {
           $(this)... // Original javascript code which obviously not correct in typescript
       }
    }
}
```

However in TypeScript this in a class method "this" always refers to the class instance. I would like to access the very same object what it would be in pure javascript.

*In general: What is the way to access the original javascript context (this) in a callback when using TypeScript?*

Comment: If I understand, you want to get elm instead this?

Comment: *"However in TypeScript this in a class method "this" always refers to the class instance."* Are you sure? That's seems like a big deviation from JavaScript. OTOH, I have no idea bout typescript.

Comment: @FelixKling Yes I am sure. Positive.

Comment: @itsgoingdown: you may right. It is suspicious why the author in the original javascript sample is using $(this) instead of $(elm). Anyway the generic question is still "how to access the original javascript context (this) in a callback when using TypeScript?"

Comment: @g.pickardou Perhaps the function is [bound](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/bind) to the class instance? Otherwise, what you've described doesn't seem to be the default behavior. https://jsfiddle.net/40mgowen/

Comment: @JonathanLonowski: Many thanks. My bad, I mixed the TypeScrip behaviour when it behaves when using lambdas " ()=> {}" instead of "function () {}" The best would be delete this stupid question,  but I unfortunately can not because it has an answer. So the best option you post this comment as answer.

Comment: @FelixKling: You were right. My bad

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is not accurate.

When using `this` in lambda expression or in a class method, it refers to the class itself. Examples:

```
class A{
  public a:number;
  public foo(){
     this.a = 1;//this here is A
     var lambda = () => { this.a = 2; } //this here is A
     var fn = function() { this.a = 3; } // this here is not the A
  }
}
```

You can look at the transpiled code here: [Typescript Playground](http://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#src=%20%20%20%20class%20A%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20public%20a%3Anumber%3B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20public%20foo()%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20this.a%20%3D%201%3B%2F%2Fthis%20here%20is%20A%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20var%20lambda%20%3D%20()%20%3D%3E%20%7B%20this.a%20%3D%202%3B%20%7D%20%2F%2Fthis%20here%20is%20A%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20var%20fn%20%3D%20function()%20%7B%20this.a%20%3D%203%3B%20%7D%20%2F%2F%20this%20here%20is%20not%20the%20A%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%7D%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%7D)